# iskeyword for latex

Tags: filetype-tex, variables

### Context

Currently, when I `set ft=tex`, my `set isk?` reads

```
iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255
```

that is, the default for vim.

### My "issue"

Currently, in a LaTeX string such as

```
$\abcde_\fgh$
```

the `w` jump would take me from the start to

1. `a`
2. `\`
3. `f`
4. `$`

Thus, the above setting does not feel very natural, nor optimal.

Indeed, it would probably be more reasonable to jump to

1. `\`
2. `_`
3. `\`
4. `$`

### My attempt

I'm thinking of something more like `set iskeyword=\,192-255`
so as to have words consist of characters that would fit in

- natural language words
- or LaTeX commands.

### Questions

1. Is it supposed to be so ? *yes, since it is the default*
2. What are better settings ?
3. How to properly set this variable for this filetype ?

Cheers,

Comment: I cross-asked [this question on TeX-SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/365200/116936). Hope this is acceptable.

Comment: I'm not familiar with editing this setting, but `@,48-57,_,192-255` is the [default for vim](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27iskeyword%27). Perhaps you can tell us why it feels unnatural or what you are expecting vs. the behavior you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get **all** LaTeX strings right using `iskeyword`, that is because the `iskeyword` works on characters and some characters may have different meanings in different contexts.  A better way than <kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>w</kbd> to test `iskeyword` is <kbd>viw</kbd> which should visually select all characters from the cursors in both directions until it hits a character that is not in `iskeyword`.

On example of where this is useful are quoted strings, for example:

```
"abc"
```

Here <kbd>viw</kbd> will select `abc` and not the double quotes.  But LaTeX can be ambiguous, how about this:

```
"Bj\{"o}rn"
```

Therefore a way to finding all possible LaTeX commands that can be inside a natural language word would require you to set `iskeyword` to everything but non-printables (space, tab, and special characters).

*But Vim already does that for you!*

If instead of using <kbd>viw</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>w</kbd>, you use <kbd>viW</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>W</kbd> you are selecting Vim WORDs (not words).  Vim makes a distinction between WORDs and words.  See `:h WORD`:

> A WORD consists of a sequence of non-blank characters, separated with white
>   space.  An empty line is also considered to be a WORD.
>
> (...)

---

Therefore:

> 1. Is it supposed to be so? *yes, since it is the default*

And moreover since the `tex.vim` ftplugin did not overwrite it.

> 2. What are better settings?

You probably should not play with `iskeyword`, different file types will have different ones but most use the defaults.  Messing with `iskeyword` in vimrc may become a burden when you overwrite it for a filetype that needs it (you could write your own ftplugin for TeX but there is no real need here).  Instead use WORDs where you need them.

> 3. How to properly set this variable for this filetype?

See above.

---

<sub>P.S. I wrote my entire dissertation in LaTeX, and all in Vim.  I have been before where you are now :).</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not what I ask for. The capital versions deal with WORDs (sequences of non-whitespace characters). Here the whole example string is only one WORD, when I would like 5 words : the two '$', the two '\commands' and the '_'.

Comment: You make a good point about non-ASCII characters being escaped in natural language (`Bj{\"o}rn`), but I write accents in plain text (`Björn`), and thus don't really care about the exception you raise.

Comment: And for the record, I am not actually a new user of TeX nor vim.
I have been writing LaTeX for ten years, and using vim for 5.

Comment: Also `iskeyword` is local to a buffer.

Comment: "You probably should not play with iskeyword" Limiting your changes to a specific filetype `au FileType tex set iskeyword=whatever` is easy enough, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think what I want is too complicated for `iskeyword`.

This is because `iskeyword` does not use regex.

But, in what I want, a backslash could only appear as the start of a word.

For now, I think the following lines in my `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` may improve my quality of life when editing `tex` files :

```
set isk-=_
nmap w /\\\\|\\\@<!\<\k\\|\(\>\\|\s\)\@<=\S<CR>:noh<CR>
nmap b ?\\\\|\\\@<!\<\k\\|\(\>\\|\s\)\@<=\S<CR>:noh<CR>
```

It enables to jump to next / previous

- backslash
- or word not starting with a backslash
- or non-blank character preceded by the end of a word or some whitespace

Basically, I use

```
/\<\k<CR>:noh<CR>
```

as an approximation for `w` and patch from there.

The obvious drawback is that it fills the search history with junk !

Cheers,