# non-word characters in tags

Tags: autocompletion, ctags

I have tags (generated with `ctag`) of the form

`eq:local-canonical-form`

Now:

1. because of the `:` I cannot use `eq:loc<c-x><c-]>` to expand the tag.
2. because of the `:` and the `-` I cannot use `<c-]>` to jump to its definition...

Any ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: Try `:set iskeyword+=:`. If it helps, you can put `setlocal iskeyword+=:` into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`. BTW recommended by [vim-latex aka latex-suite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/recommended-settings.html).

Comment: that's neat. it works for both these characters!!

Comment: actually I'm trying to get some `vim-latex` functionality to `rmarkdown`

Comment: @Hotschke i think that could be an answer?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: For me it looks like this question is a duplicate of https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16686/unable-to-set-iskeyword-for-colon-character. However, if you do not know what `iskeyword` is, the title is not very helpful. Oh, no this question wants the opposite. My mistake.

Comment: @Hotschke at first glance they are similar, but technically that QA is the reverse of this one, removing colon rather than adding it to iskeyword

Comment: I now noticed this as well. I am suprised about the other one because by default `:` is not in iskeyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, in vim (and most other editors) `:` and `-` separate words. This means word/tag completion do not complete `eq:loc<c-x><c-]>` but only `loc<c-x><c-]>`. If there is no tag `loc...`, nothing happens.

You can fix this by placing

```
setlocal iskeyword+=:
setlocal iskeyword+=-
```

in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` and/or `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/rmd.vim` (rmd=rmarkdown).

However, this might have surprising side effects. For instance, if you have the equation `a-b:2`, it is now treated as a single word.

The situation in latex is known to be complicated:

> You can't get all LaTeX strings right using iskeyword, that is because the iskeyword works on characters and some characters may have different meanings in different contexts. (from *[iskeyword for latex](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12117/iskeyword-for-latex)*)

Someone already asked the question *[iskeyword with context](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13830/iskeyword-with-context)*. But the answer is not affirmative to solve this issue.